# using the Youtube Data API v3 in Processing

Tags: api, video, youtube, upload, processing

I have an processing sketch that shows and records the webcam feed. It exports the video to an .mp4.
How can I use the Youtube Data API v3 in processing? I want to upload the .mp4 to Youtube.

I saw this example: http://www.benfarahmand.com/2013/09/tutorial-using-youtube-data-api-in.html
But I didn't got it to work.

So how can I use the Youtube Data API v3 in processing?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

Comment: Please be more specific than saying "I didn't got it to work." What exactly did you try? Post screenshots if you can, and copy any error messages you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Processing editor, or are you using Processing as a library itself?

If you're using the Processing editor, then you just need to drag the YouTube libary `.jar` file(s) onto the Processing editor. Then you can use them exactly like you'd use any other library.

If you're using Processing as a library itself (in an IDE like eclipse), then you have to add the YouTube library `.jar` file(s) to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse go to the Eclipse Marketplace and search for the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/).  After downloading it click on your project.  Then click on the blue Google button in the toolbar and select "Add API..".  Search for the Youtube API you want and select it.  This will add all the relevant JAR files to your project in one swoop, big time saver!